# How to pass each firebase database entries into react - native components in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase project looks like - 
[image]

Suppose I have multiple database entries in the announcements, then which is the best way to pass each announcement entry to a react - native component which takes `Popup` and `Longtext` as `props`.

I tried something like this:

```js
returnNotificationCards() {
  var newArr = this.state.notContainer;
  return newArr.map((line) => {
    return <NotificationCards Popup = {
      line.Popup
    }
    longText = {
      line.Longtext
    }
    />
  });

}

componentDidMount() {
  let dataContainer
  firebase.database().ref('/announcements/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      dataContainer.push(childData)
    });
  });
  this.setState({
    notContainer: dataContainer
  })
}
```

But the code is not working. Here the component to which the Firebase data should be passed is `NotificationCards`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked fine when I passed firebase data from the parent component of the current component via `goToNotifications()`

```js
goToNotifications() {
  var dataContainer = []
  firebase.database().ref('/announcements/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      dataContainer.push(childData);
    });
    Actions.Notifications({
      dataContainer
    })
  });
}
```

And returned to `NotificationCards` component through the current component via `displayNotifi()`

```js
displayNotifi() {
  var fetcheData = this.props.dataContainer;
  return fetcheData.map((line) => {
    return <NotificationCards Popup = {
      JSON.stringify(line.Popup).replace(/\"/g, "")
    }
    longText = {
      JSON.stringify(line.Longtext).replace(/\"/g, "")
    }
    />
  });
}
```